# Trying to copy a file from server to client

Tags: 14.04, server, files, transfer

Im trying to copy a file from my server to a client account I have, I am logged in to the server from my client and am having troubles copying a file over. I use the command: (tried with and without sudo)

```
scp jay@192.168.1.129:./sshd* .         ## client is 192.168.1.129
```

When I enter the command I am prompted for jay@192.168.1.129's password, I enter it, then I get

```
scp: ./sshd*: No such file or directory
```

However I know that the file is there I just viewed it with ls
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Essentially I need to email the file I am trying to copy, to do this I need to get it off the server and over to either a client or a usb drive to compress this with other files located elsewhere (hence the copy), btw this is being done in a virtual machine using VMware.

Comment: Try this without sudo and report back...

Comment: Also, get rid of the space between the colon and the file name. Your final command should be `scp jay@192.168.1.129:/etc/ssh/sshd_config.modified_assignment .`.

Comment: @user284635: That means that that file doesn't exist on the remote system. Perhaps you were trying to copy `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` from the remote system to a file named `modified_assignment` on your local system? (also, please use the @-tags at the start of the question so that other commenters know you've responded.)

Comment: @saiarcot895 Thanks for the tip.... I modified my ssh file and saved it as sshd_config.modified_assignment, I know the file is there because I just viewed it in the original directory and I just copied it to the servers home directory and am viewing it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, you keep using incorrect syntax (including your before edited versions of the command).

```
scp jay@192.168.1.129:/home/jay/sshd* ./
```

should work. Or this , if I have client and server backwards:

```
scp sshd* jay@192.168.1.129:/home/jay/
```

By the way, I much prefer to keep the original time stamp:

```
scp -p sshd* jay@192.168.1.129:/home/jay/
```

Comment: Same issue.... Isnt the command you provided trying to copy the file from jays(client) directory rather than the servers?

Comment: I don't know, I thought 192.168.1.129 was the server and the command was to be executed from the client.

Comment: Other way around I'm logged into the server from the client and am trying to copy from the server to the client, Thanks for your time